# What is the use of .profile-empty file in Tensorflow events folder

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

There is this file (events.out.tfevents.1611631707.8f60fbcf7419.profile-empty) that appears alongside other files e.g. events.out.tfevents.1611897478.844156cf4a75.61.560.v2.
My model training is not going well at all so I am looking all over to identify things I don't understand to see if they may be the cause. What is this .profile-empty file for? An image below to show the files.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a file written by the TensorFlow profiler. It is here to help the TensorBoard know which directory contains the profile data.

From the commit [`c66b603`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/c66b603990b9404dc1eb57de9d595aa0ffc8197f):

> save empty event file in logdir when running profiler. TensorBoard will use this event file to identify the logdir that contains profile data

And from the commit [`23d8e38`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/23d8e38f8728b7107d78a773e03f8b1a8166237a):

> Save an empty event file when StartTracing is called. This is to help with TensorBoard subdirectory searching.